# Add Tailwind CSS to Angular Cypress Component Test

Tags: angular, cypress

unfortunately I can't manage to include the tailwind styles in the (Cypress/Angular) component test. I already tried to import the styles in `cypress/support/component.ts`. However, I get an error here.

```
The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.

  > Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)

You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

> @tailwind base;
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea at all how to include them.

I thank you for any help.

Comment: This question is related to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74507350/how-to-include-scss-styles-in-angular-cypress-component-testing (which is also without a correct answer for now)

Comment: hi i actually got it to work :) I'm sorry that I answer only now. The problem was Angular libs that also use Tailwind. So I just have to include them in the tailwind.config file. like:

`
module.exports = {
 content: {
  './node_modules/@my-lib/**/*.{js, mjs}'
}
}
`